# How to use the JNA base and how to resolve a memory reference error?

Tags: jna

I'm calling the Cribreepy I got from JNA. 
I've been trying to work it out for days, but it won't work. Can you help me?

Below are the provided C shared libraries (so):

[image]

This is JNA JAVA source code I wrote:

[image]

[image]

Below is an error:

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please edit your question to include the text from the images as text in-line with your question, as it's very difficult for us to read the 4 different image links in context.

Comment: That said, from a brief look I suspect your use of your `handle` variable in the `mmdbConnect` and `mmdbFreeHandle` calls is wrong.  You are passing the pointer to the `MmdbHandleTest` structure, but it looks like that structure has a `mHandle` element which may be what you want.

Comment: I haven't uploaded an image yet because it's my first subscription to Stack Overflow. Sorry